# Bluetooth codec settings resetting on re-connection

Tags: bluetooth, android-11, developer-options

I've got a Surface Duo 2 running Android 11 (build 2021.827.34) paired with some Sony MDR-1000X bluetooth headphones. The Sonys support LDAC and so does the phone (hurrah!), unfortunately when running at full quality (990kbps 96khz) I get choppy/stuttering audio during playback or when doing certain operations on the phone (waking via the power button for example guarantees a ~1sec stutter).

I enabled developer options and used the bluetooth codec settings there to reduce sample rate to 88.2kHz which successfully eliminates the stuttering while retaining LDAC's quality benefits, the problem is that this setting reverts each time I disconnect and re-connect the headphones. Is there any way to make these changes persistent?

Comment: Similar https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS8/comments/7x8y8k/set_ldac_as_default_on_oreo/

Comment: [Disabling multi point](https://www.reddit.com/r/sony/comments/kk91wi/question_how_to_force_ldac_on_android_10_with/) seems to help

Comment: @beeshyams Sadly neither of those help. I *can* turn LDAC off completely by disabling the LDAC option on on the device in the "regular" settings for the Bluetooth device and that change will persist through a disconnect-reconnect (only changes made to Developer Settings are lost).

Comment: Try Sony connect apps like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sony.songpal) // app description screenshot shows LDAC//Also see settings for your Sony that may help https://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/1000x/v1/en/contents/TP0001176179.html

Comment: @beeshyams The Sony app(s) don't support the MDR-1000X unfortunately. Changing the settings on the headphones themselves only allows me to set them to set them to SBC only so no joy there.